# The role of the asterisks (kinds, *) in this Foldable instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, type-kinds

In the [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) documentaion, I see the following instance:

```
(Foldable f, Foldable g) => Foldable (Compose * * f g)
```

If I look at the definition of [Compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose), I see it is declared as

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose f (g a)
```

which has kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> * -> *`, right? (which I suppose it is inferred). Now as far as I can see, I guess it would be correct to write:

```
(Foldable f, Foldable g) => Foldable (Compose f g)
```

Since `Compose f g` has also kind `* -> *`. However, I guess the two `kind` identifiers are there for a reason. But what is this reason?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the documentation generation; the extra `*` appear in the documentation for `Compose`, `Product`, and `Sum` instances, but not in the source itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the kind of `Compose` is more general if you turn on `PolyKinds` :

```
newtype Compose (f :: k -> *) (g :: k' -> k) (a :: k') = Compose (f (g a))
```

This type is inferred with `PolyKinds` and requires it to write (and it is defined as such in the [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Compose.html#Compose) - note that `PolyKinds` is enabled in the module).

Technically, this
`Compose` takes two *kind* parameters, which are implicit. This means you do not normally specify them, nor can you normally see them. However, it is a peculiarity of the Haddocks that they do display kind parameters. But if you are interested, you can see the same thing in GHCi, with e.g.

```
>:set -fprint-explicit-kinds
>import Data.Functor.Compose
>:i Compose
type role Compose nominal nominal representational nominal nominal
newtype Compose k k1 (f :: k -> *) (g :: k1 -> k) (a :: k1)
  = Compose {getCompose :: f (g a)}
        -- Defined in `Data.Functor.Compose'
....
instance [safe] (Foldable f, Foldable g) =>
                Foldable (Compose * * f g)
```

Note that `Compose` is given two kind arguments - `*` and `*` - because `f` and `g` must be of kind `* -> *` due to the `Functor` constraints.

Comment: Thanks. But is it necessary to use PolyKinds? I thought the compiler was smart enough to figure this out.

Comment: Figure what out? Regular Haskell does not allow for kind variables - such a type signature would not even be valid. GHC conforms to Haskell 2010 by default, so it wouldn't even permit you to write the type declaration as given - it would tell you to turn on `PolyKinds`.